# Change Form label in static void GetResponseCallback

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Hi I try to change label element but text not changing.

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
        {       
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                sendPOST("http://example");            
            }

            public static void sendPOST(string URL)
            {
                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URL);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = "POST";

                // start the asynchronous operation
                request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback),request);

                allDone.WaitOne();        
            }

private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            // Convert the string into a byte array.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");

            // Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
           {
              //.....
              Form1 test = new Form1();
              test.statusLabel.Text  = responseString; //dont write anything

               Console.WriteLine(responseString); //works well
              //.....
        }
```

How can I change it?

**UPDATE: Add more code**. How can I obtain existing Form1 instance to update Form1 LabelField to show something after asyn is done?

Comment: how can I access to existing Form1 instance from static GetResponseCallback ?

Comment: @Servy, update code, please look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on the questions I guess you could do this: Pass the form's instance you want to change as a user defined object `state` to the call that leads to `GetResponseCallback` being called (most  `BeginXYZ` methods allow you to pass a user defined object, which is then in `IAsyncResult.State`). Then you can do something like this:

```
Form1 test = asynchronousResult.State as Form1;
test.StatusLabel.Text = responseString;
```

Please note that due to multithreading issues you may not be allowed to change the `Text` property and have to use `Control.Invoke` to do so. There are many threads on SO that describe this.

I don't have a working code sample right now, but if I'm not mistaken, it should look something like this:

```
test.Invoke((Action)delegate() { StatusLabel.Text = responseString; });
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally change my code to use thread which update main UI throw this.BeginInvoke()

Comment: Again and again... Might the downvoter **please** explain why he's downvoting!?